# How to store a list of numbers generated as output in Python?

Tags: python

Suppose I want to add several numbers together like:
1. Find even numbers between 1-100.
2. Find odd numbers between 2-200.
3. Add them.

So for this, I can check for even numbers and odd numbers respectively, but to add them, they must be stored somewhere. Now how can I do this?

i.e. store the output of the first step, store the output of second step and then add them together.

Comment: A list of numbers can be stored in a `list`. See your Python tutorial's section about lists.

Comment: You're actually wrong that the numbers have to be stored anywhere: you could just sum them directly as you find them.

Comment: Thankyou eumiro and Duncan.
@bereal I never asked for a solution to the problem, the even and odd problem was just made to explain what I wanted to learn. I just wanted to know how can I store results in a list and use them later. My actual problem is different. That is why I used 'suppose' in the beginning. Cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Find even numbers between 1-100:

```
>>> l = [i for i in range(1,101) if i % 2 == 0]
>>> print l
[2, 4, 6, ..., 100]
```

Find odd numbers between 2-200:

```
>>> l2 = [i for i in range(2,200) if i % 2 != 0]
>>> print l2
[3, 5, 7, ..., 199]
```

Find the sum:

```
>>> total = sum(l) + sum(l2)
>>> print total
12540
```

What I've done is List Comprehensions, a loop which creates values for whatever factors you want. Here's a link to the documentation about it: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Comment: Thank you so much everyone for helping me.
So, in python, we can use range to generate a list of numbers and then use sum() to add them.
But, in general ( in other programming languages or without using range) how can we store the numbers generated after a test ( like even or odd ) in a list or array to use that later to perform operations on it like addition or subtraction?

Comment: As a demonstration of list comprehension syntax, this is ok. But one should never, ever, build a list of consecutive even (or odd) numbers doing `% 2` to each candidate: finding the first and then counting in steps of two is (almost) infinitely more efficient.

Comment: @user2003243 You can use other loops to get list of numbers. Here,

`one = 1`
`mylist = []`
`while one != 101:`
`mylist.append(one)`
`one += 1`

Comment: No problem :). If you found it helpful, (I don't wish to sound greedy or anything :/) could you please one-up it or accept my answer to help other viewers who may see this forum later :).

Comment: I tried that as soon as you answered! But as this is my first question and I have zero reputation, I could not have that pleasure to vote up. :D

Comment: @user2003243 Thanks anyway :). If you have any other questions, I'll try to help.

Comment: oh yes yes, I will have a lot! I'll comment here the links.

Answer (score 2):

Even Numbers List:

```
a = [i for i in range(2,101,2)]
```

Odd Numbers List:

```
b = [i for i in range(3,200,2)]
```

Sum:

```
c = sum(a) + sum(b)
```

Comment: List b misses the number 1. So it should be range(1,200,2)

Comment: @Haidro the question  is asking for odd number between 2 and 200

Comment: @nsconnetor my mistake, sorry

Answer (score 1):

This is what containers like lists are for:

```
numbers = []  # Setup an empty list

for number in range(10):  # Loop over your numbers
    numbers.append(number)  # Append the number to your list

print sum(numbers)  # 45
```

Answer (score 0):

Results of first and second steps can be stored in 2 different lists.

```
list1 = [2, 4, 6 .. ]
list2 = [1, 3, 5 .. ]
```

Lists are documented on python docs at http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need a list.

```
>>> sum(x for x in range(1,100) if x % 2)
2500
>>> sum(x for x in range(2,200) if not x % 2)
9900
```